# Not able to change python version in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-3.11

I already have python(3.10.5) installed in my windows 10 machine. I have now installed python 3.11.1. I am trying to default setting the python version to 3.11.1 but it not working.

I have deleted 3.10.5 version from the environment variable list.

[image]

Still when I do python --version, it is showing 3.10.5.
Any pointers how can I change the python version.

Comment: When you type `python --version` in a console, only one environment variable is used: the `PATH`. If you want to get the 3.11 version by default just make sure it is present in the path (and comes before the 3.10 one...). Alternatively in Windows the common way is to use the `py` launcher: `py -3.11 --version`.